# Arrays objects duplicated and positioned at different rates

Tags: modifiers

I use a sphere and a cylinder, both relative offset of 3.
But they both are moving at different rates. And ye[image]s, both of them are scaled at 1.0.
How do I get them to both be duplicated at the same rate? All spheres should be on all cylinders.

Comment: Try using constant offset

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help. The constant offset worked.